# contact form require to fill one of two fields

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create a contact form in WordPress where one of two fields must be filled to send.
For example - `e-mail` and `telephone number` are required, but if a user fills just one field then it will be ok.

Comment: use contact form 7 plugin and while adding field in it , just select required at the field you want to be required.

Comment: Arsh, you don't understand the problem. It's logical OR operator here. Setting required on two fields, doesn't implicate relation between each other in validation process. At this moment, it's logical OR operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how you want to validate it.

PHP? You could do something like:

```
if ( empty($_POST['name1']) && empty($_POST['name2']) ) {
    // Error message
}
```

JS? You could do something like:

```
var input1Val = document.getElementsByName('name1')[0].value;
var input2Val = document.getElementsByName('name2')[0].value;

if ( input1Val.length > 0 || input2Val.length > 0 ) {
    // Allow submission
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#forgot_pass_form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        groups: {
            names: "uname email"
        },
        rules: {
            uname: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".send"]
            },
            email: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".send"]
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
        require_from_group: jQuery.format("'Please enter either username/ email address to recover password'/Please fill out at least {0} of these fields.")
    });

});`
```

And html

```
<form action="#" class="send_form" id="forgot_pass_form" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="send_row">
            <label class="padding-top10">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="send_email send" id="email" name="email"
            /> <em>You need to type an email address</em>

        </div>
        <div class="send_row option">OR</div>
        <div class="send_row">
            <label class="padding-top10">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="send_username send" id="uname"
            name="uname" />
        </div>
        <div class="send_row send_submitforgotuser">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<a id="docs" href="http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation" target="_blank">Validation Documentation</a>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sgmvY/1/

Comment: What if a user has JS disabled?

Comment: without js its not working but js must to enabled to proper website working. If without js then your code will be batter

Answer (score 0):

Validating form without js, needs developing your own form plugin.

[Here](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why/?dsh=1&utm_expid=3606929-40.lszTaIEzTbifDhvhVdd39A.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.pl%2F) is one article about it.

Change validation logic to be aware of logical OR in these two fields.